# Destructible mesh chunks cause strange collisions

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm currently working with Destructibles in Unreal Engine 4(version4.16) and i have big question about them.

I have issue that sometimes causes my player to randomly fly in the air when destroying any destructible mesh being too close. I've checked collision and it seems that chunks are the issue here. So my question is: Can i disable collision of chunks, when they are being separated from mesh?

Don't really know where shall i search for it. Any guideliness would be really helpful.

Comment: Is your destructible mesh scaled?

Comment: You mean scaled on scene? Then yes it is

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in this [troubleshooter](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Destructible_Troubleshooting_Guide#Why_is_my_collision_wrong_if_I_scale_my_DM.3F), *nonuniform scaling* does not work with destructible mesh. You should create *DM* that don't require scaling at all, or require only **uniform** scaling. To debug where your colliders are, you can use `PXVIS COLLISION` console command.

Also I'd recommend you to read all of the tips in the link mentioned earlier. It is a really helpful source.

Comment: So I've checked it and DM i'm using is scaled in proper way. What helped with my issue was changing " Large Chunk Threshold" to a bigger number, so chunks are now bouncing off my character.